# PhoneGap Browser Issue Ruby on Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, cordova

I'm trying to implement a twitter share in my app. In webbrowser im able to do it successfuly.

```
<a data-original-referer="http://lvh.me"  href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?original_referer=<%= twitter_call_back %>&text=<%= URI::encode($tweet_text) %>"></a>
```

This piece of code in my html does the task.. Thing is in webbrowser a new html page for twitter loads and so if im not interested in tweeting after i load the page i can close the browser.
But im converting this to an IOS app using phonegap. Here when i take the twitter page it loads internally on the app and if i dont want to tweet im stuck at that page.

So is there any solution to provide a back button or cancel button in twitter share page.Or is there any way to load this page in external browser via app.